# Enviar datos con Ajax y Json

Tags: php, ajax, json

Necesito trabajar con Ajax y Json. Estos 2 Códigos de debajo trabajan juntos y funcionan, me devuelve el id y el nombre.

```
<script>
    function enviarDatos(){
        $.ajax({
            data:{
                id:1,
                nombre:"foto7"
            },
            type:"GET",
            datatype:"json",
            url:"listar.php"
        })
        .done(function(datos,textStatus,jqXHR){

            respuesta1.innerHTML+="ID:"+datos.id+"<br>";
            respuesta2.innerHTML+="Categoria:"+datos.categoria+"<br>";
        })

    }
</script>

$id=$_GET['id'];
$nombre=$_GET['nombre'];

$datosJson['id']=$id;
$datosJson['nombre']=$nombre;

header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
echo  json_encode($datosJson);
exit();
```

Pero el tema es que yo necesito que en el script dónde hago la llamada ajax los datos id y nombre se recojan de un formulario. Y desconozco cuál es la síntaxis para hacer ésto. Cuándo he usado únicamente Ajax sin Json, escribia:

```
var dataString= "datos que necesito"
```

Y luego:

```
$.ajax({
        data:dataString,
   })
```

pero por lo visto con Json no es la manera correcta. He estado leyendo información pero no doy con ello. Agradecería un poco de ayuda. 
Un saludo

Comment: Te falta definir la pagina de la llamada que seria un .html y la de destino que seria un .php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te dejo un ejemplo de su ejemplo

```
 <script src="./jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
$.ajax({
    // En data puedes utilizar un objeto JSON, un array o un query string
    data: {"parametro1" : "valor1", "parametro2" : "valor2"},
    //Cambiar a type: POST si necesario
    type: "GET",
    // Formato de datos que se espera en la respuesta
    dataType: "json",
    // URL a la que se enviará la solicitud Ajax
    url: "script.php",
})
 .done(function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud se ha completado correctamente." );
     }
 })
 .fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ) {
     if ( console && console.log ) {
         console.log( "La solicitud a fallado: " +  textStatus);
     }
});
```

Comment: joerr claro! muchas gracias!!! y gracias tambien por el resto del código, mucho mas elegante y seguro

Comment: por nada amigo es un gusto ayudarte